# Inline ng-if with fa icon

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to inline ng-if?

```
<h3 ng-if="!ctrl.isSearchBoxCollapsed" class="box-title"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></h3>
<h3 ng-if="ctrl.isSearchBoxCollapsed" class="box-title"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h3>
```

Greetings 
and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) this like this:

```
<h3 class="box-title"><i class="fa" ng-class="ctrl.isSearchBoxCollapsed ? 'fa-plus-circle' : 'fa-minus-circle'"></i></h3>
```

I also suggest you to take a look at [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) that explains many way to use `ng-class`

Comment: Ah ok, I've updated the answer with a link to a useful blog post about `ng-class`